# how to get wordpress home url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

in php get_home_url()
I using ajax.

```
<script>
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.new_post_btn').click(function(){
            var dataString = {
            'action': 'new_post_action',
            'post_status': 'draft',
        };

            dataString=
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                  data: dataString,
                                    success: function(msg){
                         if(msg!='false')
                                                 {
                                                     msg=msg.substring(0, msg.length-1);
                                                     window.location='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/post.php?post='+msg+'&action=elementor';
                                                 }
                       }

                 });
        });
});
</script>
```

I want to use 'http://localhost/wordpress'  to javascript function to get wordpress home url.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to find host of the current page, then use `document.location`.

```js
console.log("document.location.href : "+ document.location.href);
console.log("document.location.origin : "+ document.location.origin);
console.log("document.location.hostname : "+ document.location.hostname);

 // --> If you want to pass another url to fetch domain home name then you can use following function.


var tmp = document.createElement('a');
tmp.href   = "http://www.example.com/my-page";
console.log("host : "+tmp.host);
console.log("Host : "+tmp.hostname);
```

Comment: The issue with your answer is that it doesn't take into account the directory where Wordpress was installed. It may be "website.com/blog/" instead of "website.com". In which case, your answer would be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You can get Wordpress's Home Url from the WP-JSON link tag as follows:

```
// get JSON url
var WpJsonUrl = document.querySelector('link[rel="https://api.w.org/"]').href
// then take out the '/wp-json/' part
var homeurl = WpJsonUrl.replace('/wp-json/','');
```